# Libraries not resolving in sbt within intellij, but resolves and compiles from commandline

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

The below sbt file doesn't resolve the spark-xml databricks package from within intelliJ Idea where as works fine with command line

```
name := "dataframes"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

val sparkVersion="1.4.0"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % sparkVersion % "provided",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % sparkVersion,
  "com.databricks" %% "spark-xml" % "0.3.3"
)

resolvers ++= Seq(
  "Apache HBase" at "https://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/releases",
  "Typesafe repository" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"
)

resolvers += Resolver.mavenLocal
```

The sbt was set to both bundled and other pointing to the locally installed sbt, but did not work either way.

The below package resolves and works perfectly from commandline

```
import com.databricks.spark._
```